# Not able to Compile and Create jar file using Netbeans 7.1 Beta version

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am compiling my code on Netbeans 7.1 Beta. Getting Following but No `copyExample.jar` is created at specified Location.

```
Created dir: E:\NIRAJ\Lodable_Creation_java\build
Updating property file: E:\NIRAJ\Lodable_Creation_java\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: E:\NIRAJ\Lodable_Creation_java\build\classes
Created dir: E:\NIRAJ\Lodable_Creation_java\build\empty
Compiling 1 source file to E:\NIRAJ\Lodable_Creation_java\build\classes
Copying 15 files to E:\NIRAJ\Lodable_Creation_java\build\classes
Copied 5 empty directories to 1 empty directory under E:\NIRAJ\Lodable_Creation_java\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: E:\NIRAJ\Lodable_Creation_java\dist
Copying 1 file to E:\NIRAJ\Lodable_Creation_java\build
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "E:\NIRAJ\Lodable_Creation_java\dist\copyexample.jar"
jar:
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: Maybe try it in the [final](http://netbeans.org/downloads/) release of NetBeans 7.1 instead of the Beta and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: As a suggestion, with unbuntu i have has a similar pb, when I was in the `dist` directory (from terminal or dir browser) Netbeans can't delete the dist directory and nothing is created. So take care nothing is listening on this directory maybe it will help!

Answer (score 1):

I think your library links is broken check it and add library in project. Then make your project clean and build. One thing keep in your mind Jar file always in dist folder. For this open NeatBeans project folder find your project and opent it you find dist folder. for stepwise creation of .Jar file check following link.

http://java4projects.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-create-jar-file-in-netbeans.html

Hope it will help you.
Thanks.